# How to use Kalman Filter with rotating object

Tags: javascript, gps, kalman-filter

I'm using "kalmanjs" library to smooth the heading from GPS data, it work correctly from 0 to 360 deg, but I don't understand how to manage the passage from 360 to 0.

Can anyone help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

The library supports linear motion only.

The easiest workaround is: When you see a delta change of more than 180 degrees (means you either passed from say 355 to 2 or from 2 to 350), you add/subtract 360 degrees from the value prior to the filter to make the change continious. In the first example above, you'd pass in 362 degrees.

You then do the reverse operation for the filter output.

That way, the filter will always handle linear changes while you normalize your values back to 0 to 360 degrees.